# Topic classification in R

Tags: r, classification, topic-modeling

I am working on a dataset of restaurant reviews and wish to filter out the reviews about hygiene specifically.

I figured out that I can come up with a bunch of words that is hygiene related (clean, dirty, soap, germs …) and match all the words in the reviews. Is there a specific library that I can use for that? Or perhaps a more sophisticated method to do this? Thank you so much :)

I have tried LDA which gave me the topic models, however I did not find any hygiene related topics. Perhaps they are not salient enough. Yup